# When updating JLabel, previous text stays, and old text is placed on top of it

Tags: java, jlabel

So, I'm making a program, and on the program, it displays your health in this format:

```
Health : 82/82
```

When you take Damage, I ask the program to update the `JLabel`, and it would display that you took damage like this

```
Health: 60/82
```

The `JLabel` is a public variable, and is only being created once,

```
public JLabel UIHealth = new JLabel();
```

and from then on is updated with the below code.
Here is the code I use to update the `UIHealth JLabel` updating the text after an action occures:

```
UIHealth.setText("Health: "+Health+"/"+PlayerHealthBar.getMaximum()+"");
```

Is there a simpler way to display text that will be updated?
Does it matter that my Frame and ALL panels are set to be transparent to see the image behind it that acts as a HUD?
Here is the code I applied to everything that is transparent, but still interactive.

```
public Color Clear = new Color(0,0,0,0);
```

and I would of course call `Clear` when using the `.setBackground` component.

here is an image of after taking a bit of damage (4-5 hits) looks on the UI. (Take note of how the text just stacks on top of itself)

[image: UI After taking a few hits]

Thanks in advance for all your time.
Please let me know and ask me if something seems unclear, or you need other snippets of my program.

Comment: Is `UIHealth` a `JLabel`? If so, note that my confusion has been partly caused by a lack of adherence to standard Java naming conventions.

Comment: UIHealth is a JLabel, I'll edit that in so it's clear to everyone else that checks this question.

Comment: Im new to asking questions, so I'm trying to present it the best I can, I'm sorry that the question wasn't as clear as possible

Comment: are you creating new JLabel instances everytime you want to change the value? can you post that code?

Comment: Your question is fine. But in Java, variables/fields should start with a lowercase letter (e.g. `uiHealth`). When Java programmers see this convention ignored, we get confused about whether it is a field or a class with a static method.

Comment: @KAdithyan Adithyan, `UIHealth` is a public variable. It's created once, and then has the text updated from there on out. I've updated my question to make that clear for new people coming in. @DuncanJones, I understand, I'll go through and update all my variables for the sake of convention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `JPanel` that you are adding your label to. You need to call `myPanel.setOpaque(false);` after creating it.

Comment: As a mater of fact, `JLabel UIHealth` has not been altered with `.setBackground()` However, the Panels that it nests itself in, have been altered with `.setBackground()` Could this pose an issue with the `JLabel UIHealth`?

Comment: i just realised you don't need to call `repaint()`

Comment: Thank you!! `myPanel.setOpaque(false);` requires less effort then calling `repaint()` to each individual `JPanel`. Thanks for teaching me something new, the program works as intended now